# PhpMyAdmin: file and line exact where QUERY "SELECT" is executed?

Tags: php

know some person the FILE and LINE where PMA execute the QUERY "by default" to select X rows from ANY table ?

`phpMyAdmin 5.1.1`

when I try find this FILE+LINE I find two files into `/tmp` folder:

```
phpMyAdmin-5.1.1-all-languages\tmp\twig\67\6713c2eddaa7a146c29b5dfe966a6717694167b6b99f58e35222aab2bc4f92b3.php
phpMyAdmin-5.1.1-all-languages\tmp\twig\c9\c934314868d98512d8034e9147a54a1771010d4253cb827d5115e58d54db6f5c.php
```

but this files are only TEMPLATES html

the principal reason to I search this LINE is learn from the algorithm used by this professional tool

some idea about the LINE and file where:

```
$mysqli -> QUERY($sql_query);
```

is executed?, I only find the function

```
getDefaultSqlQueryForBrowse($db, $table)
```

but this RETURN part of QUERY into var `$sql_query` and not execute that.

Answer (score 0):

for the version `phpMyAdmin-5.1.1-all-languages` (Released 2021-06-04) into the file

```
phpMyAdmin-5.1.1-all-languages\libraries\classes\Sql.php
```

around the line `140` you will find the function

```
private function getSqlWithLimitClause(array &$analyzed_sql_results)
```

then ADD this line BEFORE of `return`:

```
file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.date('Y-m-d_').'_QUERY_.php', __FILE__."\n".Query::replaceClause(
            $analyzed_sql_results['statement'],
            $analyzed_sql_results['parser']->list,
            'LIMIT ' . $_SESSION['tmpval']['pos'] . ', '
            . $_SESSION['tmpval']['max_rows']
        ));
```

and you will obtain the QUERY default